# Can not Run Node.js server file

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js. 
I have my NodeServer.js file which has below code.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 60000;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
console.log("Listening on port " + port);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat' });
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });
});
```

When I run this from command prompt , by below code

```
D:\Path to my application>Node NodeServer.js
```

It shows message like

```
   info  - socket.io started
   Listening on port 60000
```

But when I try to connect to this port from browser by `http://127.0.0.1:60000`, it shows me below error in command prompt

```
D:\Path to my application\node_modules\expres
s\lib\application.js:119
  this._router.handle(req, res, function(err) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined
```

What am I Doing wrong?

### Above issue is solved:

### Below is my EDIT

Below is my client Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:60000');

});
```

Below is my desing

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:60000/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="NodeClient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my application I get error of `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:60000/socket.io/socket.io.js"`

Comment: I think u have to use app.get("/", function(req,res){  your logic should go here });

Comment: @Subburaj : Thanks, it works, but now I am getting another error while I run my Client side script.
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:60000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: 404 means the file u requested is not there in the specified path..check that..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by below steps.

1. I moved my ClientScript to one specific folder(Scripts).(Say my client Script's name is NodeClient.js)
2. I removed `app.get("/", function(req,res){ your logic should go here });` function from Server script.
3. added below code `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Scripts'));`

Now it is working the way I want.
I don't know whether it is right way or not, but it is working now for me.

Answer (score 0):

change the following line

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
```

by

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);
```

app.listen(port) returns an object but we have to run the socket.io and express in same port. To do that simply pass the port variable

Comment: Any explanation as to why changing that line would make it work?

Comment: app.listen(port) returns an object but we have to run the socket.io and express in same port. To do that simply pass the port variable.